# Why has Graph Api Explorer more access to user info than my app with same scope access tokens?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to get some public information, such as hometown and current location. To get that, I only need a valid access token, no matter the scope of it.

When I query for a user who I'm not friends with on Graph Api Explorer without an access token, I can't see this info. But when I get an access token, I get the info just right.

Now, I tried the same thing with my app but had no luck despite changing the scope of the access token.

Is there a way to access this kind of public info through the graph API (I'm using the Javascript SDK) from my app?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the facebook documentation about your question

> The Graph API as such allows you to easily access all public
>   information about an object.          For example,
>   https://graph.facebook.com/btaylor (Bret Taylor) returns all the
>   public information about Bret. For example a user's first name, last
>   name and profile picture are publicly available.
>
> To get additional information about a user, you must first get their
>   permission. At a high level, you need to get an access token for the
>   Facebook user.

To get private information from a user, you'll have to get their permission, which will give you an access token for THAT user.

** EDIT  -  To expound on my answer, your app access token won't make private information about users accessible to you.  Only what they have as public info, will be public.  That goes for other users and applications.  Only what they want the outside world to see, can the outside world see.

Comment: But the data I'm trying to access is public. Graph Api Explorer shows it.

Comment: If your using https://graph.facebook.com/user_id, then all you can access publicly is id, name, first_name, last_name, link, username, gender, locale.  Other than that, you'll need an access token for that particular user, which will only work for the particular app requesting it.  No matter what the graph explorer shows, without permission that's all you can access.

Comment: OK, so the question should really be: Does Graph Api Explorer show more info than a regular app could get with the same kind of access token?